# pexpect to pass password to a script

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, pexpect

I'm trying to run a code which will trigger a script.
The script evaluates something and uploads the results to a site for which it prompts password from user. Need to automate this with a generic user.

I have

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,cwd=path)
p.wait()
```

When this runs, it evaluates something and prompts for password.
How to give this password using pexpect?
Is there any other solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [spawn class](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class)

```
p = ['cmd','to','run']
child = pexpect.spawn(' '.join(p), cwd='/path/to/dir')
# Now you give a regex of the expected password prompt
# usually use 'pass.*'
# but for a general case use '.*'
child.expect('.*')
child.sendline('abc123')  # your secure password
child.wait()
```

Comment: i wrote something like this. But It kept waiting. Not sure why...

import pexpect  

cmd=['python','example.py']  
cwd='path'  
child=pexpect.spawn(' '.join(cmd),cwd=cwd)  
child.expect('.*')  
child.sendline('password')  
child.wait()  

In example.py I had this:  

import time  
import datetime  

for i in range (3):  
        print i  
        time.sleep(1)  
        print (datetime.datetime.now())  

k=raw_input("Password:")  

if k=='password':  
        print "entered"  
else:  
        print "Not entered"

Comment: Not sure of the problem because it works for me. Don't expect to see anything printed on the screen because you aren't capturing the output stream of example.py. Try making files instead of printing `"entered"`